# Overloading method that contains super.method() of the same name

Tags: java, oop

**Before someone says this is a dupe, I looked at the other answers regarding super.super.method() but the answer to this question is not there.**

I work with a library that overloads a method in several levels:

```
class Level0 {
     public void sameName() {}
}

class Level1 extends Level0 {
     public void sameName() {
          someActions();
          super.sameName();
     }
}

class Level2 extends Level1 {
     public void sameName() {
          someOtherActions();
          super.sameName();
     }
}
```

Suppose I am writing class Level3 and I want to modify method sameName() in Level2. However, the code in Level0, Level1 and Level2 is frozen and I can't change it. **What is the best practice (or at least sane approach) when dealing with this situation?**

The natural way would be calling super.super.sameName() but for obvious reasons, Java does not allow that. Am I stuck with having co copy Level2 and modifying it there? What if I had to modify sameName() in Level1?

Comment: If I understand correctly, there are actions being called in `Level2`'s `sameName()` that you now want to "cancel" - this would actually be an argument to extend `Level1` instead (though I'm sure it's more complicated).

Comment: If your biggest worry is that you have to copy code, does that mean that there's a lot of code to copy at various levels of "sameName"? Perhaps what you need to do is template out the functionality of "sameName" so if subclasses really need their own implementation they can do it with a few simpler lines.

Comment: Curious to know what the library does; from an oops design perspective, this approach is poor and the decorator pattern is highly recommended.

Comment: @Paul Bellora: Each Level actually adds a lot of functionality, that's why I want to add on top of that instead of extending Level1.

Comment: @Ocelot20: Each Level adds more features, what I'm trying to do is 1. use most of the features of Level2 2. I want slightly different functionality of one of these features and 3. add some features myself. All that while I can't change anything outside Level3 because it is in an external library. It means that if I want to overload sameName() of Level2 in Level3, I would have to call sameName() in a grandparent class Level1.

Comment: @Scorpion: The question was inspired by AndEngine's implementation of ParallaxBackground, which builds upon ColorBackground which builds upon BaseBackground, but I was just curious about what are my options from an OOP perspective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the same thing in `Level3` - `someOtherOtherActions()` and then `super.sameName()`. If you really want to modify the behaviour of `Level2` rather than extend on it - you don't have other options. And that's a good thing - each class defines its method and doesn't allow others to modify them (just to override them).

You can look for plugs by which you can modify the method behaviour, but that depends on the particular code. For example, if `someOtherActions()` is protected, you can override it with a blank implementation that does not call `super.someOtherActions()`.

Comment: The problem is that I can't override a method in Level2 that uses super.sameName() unless I call super.sameName() myself in Level3 and then undo undesired actions of parent class.